# Draw polygon with coordinates

Tags: c#, coordinates, draw, polygon, paintevent

I'm trying to draw a Polygon with coordinates, sounds pretty simple, but there's a problem and it's not drawing. I'm using Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio 14.

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.01055

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DrawPolygon(
        Pen pen,
        Point[] points
        )
    { 

        public void DrawPolygonPoint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
               //Creer Pen
               Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.black, 3);

               //Creer points polygones
               Point point1 = new Point(10, 10);
               Point point2 = new Point(13, 11);
               Point point3 = new Point(15, 30);
               Point point4 = new Point(17, 10);
               Point point5 = new Point(20, 10);
               Point point6 = new Point(30, 15);
               Point point7 = new Point(30, 30);
               Point point8 = new Point(60, 40);
               Point point9 = new Point(65, 55);
               Point point10 = new Point(40, 60);
               Point point11 = new Point(40, 65);
               Point point12 = new Point(58, 70);
               Point point13 = new Point(60, 60);
               Point point14 = new Point(90, 60);
               Point point15 = new Point(90, 85);
               Point point16 = new Point(70, 61);
               Point point17 = new Point(60, 85);
               Point point18 = new Point(30, 85);
               Point point19 = new Point(12, 80);
               Point point20 = new Point(12, 78);
               Point point21 = new Point(16, 75);
               Point point22 = new Point(13, 68);
               Point point23 = new Point(17, 65);
               Point point24 = new Point(6, 62);
               Point point25 = new Point(16, 60);
               Point point26 = new Point(28, 56);
               Point point27 = new Point(27, 45);
               Point point28 = new Point(15, 32);
               Point point29 = new Point(15, 50);
               Point point30 = new Point(5, 50);
               Point point31 = new Point(10, 40);

               Point[] curvePoints =
               {
                    point1,
                    point2,
                    point3,
                    point4,
                    point5,
                    point6,
                    point7,
                    point8,
                    point9,
                    point10,
                    point11,
                    point12,
                    point13,
                    point14,
                    point15,
                    point16,
                    point17,
                    point18,
                    point19,
                    point20,
                    point21,
                    point22,
                    point23,
                    point24,
                    point25,
                    point26,
                    point27,
                    point28,
                    point29,
                    point30,
                    point31

                };

                 //Dessiner polygone
                 e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints);
      }
}
}
```

3 Errors are resulting. I think the major one is

> CS1061: object has no definition for 'DrawPolygon'.
>
> CS0117: 'Color' has no definition for 'black'

Any ideas on solving this? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...isn't `PaintEventArgs` for Windows Forms?  In WPF, one does not _on paint_

Comment: Yes I think so, what can I use instead in WPF? canvas?

Answer (score 1):

> what can I use instead in WPF? canvas?

WPF does have canvas but I generally use them for something else. We do have an `Image` which we can draw to indirectly.  The `Image` can be plonked pretty much anywhere in your XAML.

You can render to a `RenderTarget` which is essentially an offscreen buffer.  The output of which can be used as the input for a source for an `Image`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 


        Point[] curvePoints =
        {
            new Point(10, 10),
            new Point(13, 11),
            new Point(15, 30),
            new Point(17, 10),
            new Point(20, 10),
            new Point(30, 15),
            new Point(30, 30),
            new Point(60, 40),
            new Point(65, 55),
            new Point(40, 60),
            new Point(40, 65),
            new Point(58, 70),
            new Point(60, 60),
            new Point(90, 60),
            new Point(90, 85),
            new Point(70, 61),
            new Point(60, 85),
            new Point(30, 85),
            new Point(12, 80),
            new Point(12, 78),
            new Point(16, 75),
            new Point(13, 68),
            new Point(17, 65),
            new Point(6, 62),
            new Point(16, 60),
            new Point(28, 56),
            new Point(27, 45),
            new Point(15, 32),
            new Point(15, 50),
            new Point(5, 50),
            new Point(10, 40)
        };

        var pointCollection = new PointCollection(curvePoints);
        var polygon = new Polygon
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.GreenYellow,
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Fill = Brushes.Blue,
            Points = pointCollection
        };

        const int cx = 800;
        const int cy = 600;
        polygon.Measure(new Size(cx, cy)); 
        polygon.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, cx, cy)); 


        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(cx, cy, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(polygon);

        _image.Source = bmp;

    }
}
```

Assuming you have XAML like so (because the above code refers to an `Image` element named "_image" element in the XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPolygon1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfPolygon1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image x:Name="_image"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, you don't have to use XAML like I did, feel free to create the `StackPanel` and `Image` progmatically at runtime!

### Tell me more

- MSDN, *"RenderTargetBitmap Class"*, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3558419 Great to hear.  Don't forget to upvote, mark as answer if you think so. It helps pay the bills ;)  Have fun WPF'ing!